# Getting w3validation error

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I am trying to validate my page and getting the following w3 validation error for the following line,

```
 <li ><a href="javascript:void(0);"title="Test 33">Test 33</a>
  -   attributes construct error 
  -   Couldn't find end of Start Tag a line .....
  -   Opening and ending tag mismatch: li line ... and a
```

I am using following doctype `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Whats wrong with code ? Kindly advice on this.

Comment: You have a space in <li> and you don't close it with </li>, but with just a bunch of words it's difficult to tell..care to post the link to the page? it would be much better...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Space between `"` and `title` should do it.

Comment: @Dinesh did you try red-X solution?

Comment: @SameeraThilakasiri sorry i dont know about red-x

Comment: @Dinesh its ok, red-X means, owner of this answer, I just asked you whether you got right way :)